# Is salesforce roles case sensitive?

Tags: integration, user, roles

I have to integrate Salesforce with an external system to import users into SF. In SF we have roles manually created. The users incoming from external system will have what is called unit which is like role in SF. I want to know assuming the spelling is the same, if the unit name from external system is all caps where as in SF it is all small or vice versa or a mixture of caps and non caps, will there be a problem importing?

Comment: The fastest way to figure that out is probably for you to run a test yourself. Keep in mind, though, that the field you'd be manipulating on `User` is called `UserRoleId` (so it's an Id, not a string. Salesforce just presents the name of the related record on UI pages as a convenience).

Answer (score 0):

No and yes.
It dependes on the method of importing. If you'll be using any ETL tool it won't make much a difference because you would be able to manipulate strings, so for example if you'll be fetching UserRoleId based on api name, you can alter the process however you want.
Quite similar stuff is when handling part of the import in Apex (not recommended). You can manipulate strings to fetch UserRoleId by api name.
You won't be able to set correct roles for the users without having id of it so in the end passing name of it always will be only part of the process.